# linux - HP BLADE machines - identify the Server name from my Linux OS

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server, ilo

I have a Linux machine (RedHat version release 5.6) in HP BLADE Hardware

I am trying to find a solution to identify the server name from my Linux OS (Linux installed in the HP Blade HW), (Server name) appears in the Access Options screen

```
 Example – how to configure the server name in the HP Blade:



 from the HP Blade System Onboard Administrator screen

 I configured the server name as the following:



  click on Device Bays 

  click on ILO (  device 1 )

  click on Web Administration

  click on  Administration

  click on  Access

  click on  Options

  from the Access Options screen 

  I type the server name: barracuda1 in (Server Name:) field
```

In device Bay 1
I installed Linux redhat version release 5.6

how to discover the server name ( as already configured in Access Options screen ) from my Linux?

Or by which tool/command/SW we can identify the Server Name from Linux OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [HP ProLiant Support Pack](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=3709945&prodSeriesId=3884098&prodNameId=3884099&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-24d2642fb0c7483e99b3babad1) or management agents installed on the server to obtain this information from the Linux command line. Once installed, the `hponcfg` utility has a `-g` flag, which corresponds to "Get Host Information". The following is an example where I have a different name defined in the ILO (as you've done) than the one defined in the server's `/etc/sysconfig/network` file.

```
[root@LA_Server ~]# hponcfg -g
Firmware Revision = 2.07 Device type = iLO 2 Driver name = hpilo
Host Information:
                        Server Name: LA_Server_New
                        Server Number: 000000000
```

Comment: You mean that hponcfg exist in psp-8.73.rhel5.x86_64.en.tar.gz ? , so its fit for all HP BLADE types? , I will happy if you have other option how to find the server name via ipmi tool .

Comment: Yes, it exists within that package. It can also be downloaded individually at: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&prodNameId=3884083&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-c019e7bdb3004a708cfded1c54

Comment: did you have some idea how to identify server name via ipmi?

Comment: No. `hponcfg` is the right tool to query this information. You should probably have the HP agents installed anyway.

Comment: thanks Ewwhite for the great solution, I also want to perform auto inserting of the server name in to the HP blade , I mean if there are some other simple ways to automate the server name procedure in place the manual inserting , as you know the manual procedure is to insert the server name to each HW machine , in this way its take allot of time and I want to automate the process  - did you have some brilliant idea

Comment: If you install the HP Management Agents on the Linux server (blade), the server's $HOSTNAME will be automatically populated in the ILO  configuration.

Comment: please advice which agents they packages? or bin files? from where to get them? , any way my target is to read the hostname from the HP blade and to insert this hostname to the linux (/etc/sysconfig/network

Answer (score 0):

Try [dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) - it might contain the information you set in iLO. If not, take a look at [ipmitool](http://ipmitool.sourceforge.net/manpage.html) - it is capable of reading information from IPMI-compliant hosts, but obviously would require network connectivity.

Comment: I dont get info about servername by dmidecode , about ipmitool can you please give real example how to find the server name via ipmitool from the linux server ( I have network connectivity )